# Не могу присвоить ip адрес сокету

Tags: c, сеть

```
 net.sin_family=AF_INET;
 net.sin_port=htons(32222); 
 net.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("128.12.32.232");
   if(bind(socket1,(struct sockaddr*)&net,sizeof(net))==-1)
 {
  Perror("bind ");
  exit(1);
 }
```

Вылетает ошибка в `bind` - "не удается назначить запрошенный адрес"

почему сокету не присваивается адрес? Я хочу чтобы к нему не только мой пк подключался, но и пк друга допустим. Как присвоить публичный ip?

В интернете практически нету информации по сетям на языке си .

Comment: IP адреса присваиваются не серверам целиком, а их сетевым интерфейсам. [How to Change Your IP Address From the Command Line in Linux](https://www.howtogeek.com/118337/stupid-geek-tricks-change-your-ip-address-from-the-command-line-in-linux/)

Comment: @avp, да я понимаю что адрес присваивается сокету

Comment: По сетям информации полным-полно. Например, для программирования на Си -- https://www.tenouk.com/cnlinuxsockettutorials.html

Comment: @avp, Я имею ввиду что понятной для новичка информации крайне мало, вот написал я в Гугле "как присвоить сокету ip адрес" и нигде не было подробной инфы как по тем же массивам, приходится по крупицам собирать инфу и множество мелочей остаются непонятными

Comment: Нельзя научиться IT задавая подобные запросы в гугле. Нужно найти что-то систематизированное, прочесть и начать экспериментировать (написать несколько десятков программок). Потом уже (когда появится принципиальное понимание темы и практика написания сетевого кода) можно уточнять детали в гугле. / А адрес сокету явно присваивается вызовом `bind` (неявно -- `connect` (и `accept`, но тут вам возвращается новый сокет))

Comment: @avp, я читал книгу по си (около 400 страниц), я решал задачи в этой книге, я также купил задачник "100 примеров на си" и параллельно решал там задачки, но книгу "как научиться создавать клиент- сервер" или что то подобное не видел. И я прекрасно понимаю как присваивать адреса, в вопросе я кинул строчку которая не работает, не кидать же мне 50 строчек сюда, люди только испугаются и пропустят вопрос

Comment: [inet_addr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/inet_addr) -- *`"The inet_addr() function converts the Internet host address cp from IPv4 numbers-and-dots notation into binary data in network byte order"`*  / Зачем передаете ее результат в `htonl()`? (он уже в сетевом формате, `htonl` его портит) / И еще. Ваша строчка не присваивает адрес ни сокету, ни серверу. Вы просто заносите его в поле структуры, описывающей *какой-то* сетевой адрес. Как вы дальше эту структуру используете известно только вам.

Comment: @avp, сделал вот так: `net.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("128.12.32.232"); ` и все равно вылетает ошибка в `bind`. Сейчас добавлю строчку с `bind` в вопрос

Comment: Вы хотя бы `perror()` для отладки вызывайте. А вообще, брать  сетвые адреса "от балды" не правильно. Вы уверены, что такой localhost (все 128.... это local) существует?

Comment: @avp,Спасибо за совет) добавил функцию perror и компилятор выводит ошибку "не удается назначить запрошенный адрес"

Comment: @avp, а как это понять? Я просто вбил в поисковик "мой айпи" , скопировал его и вставил в программу.

Comment: @avp, я не хочу локалхост назначать (127.0.0.1), мне нужно сделать доступ к серверу доступным для всех желающих

Comment: Возможно вам будет полезно прочесть https://whatismyipaddress.com/private-ip (и далее) / Для успешного `bind()` 128.12.32.232 вы должны находится в [Stanford University](https://whatismyipaddress.com/ip/128.12.32.232)

Comment: @avp , да я изменил для вопроса айпишник(не знаю зачем)Правда обидно что это не мой настоящий айпи))))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> а как это понять? Я просто вбил в поисковик "мой айпи" , скопировал его и вставил в программу

Скорей всего ты не верно понимаешь, как работают/устроены ipv4 сети.

Типовая конфигурация выглядит примерно так:

```
   _____________LAN__________  ____________WAN______________ 
  /                          \/                             \
  +------+
  |      |                       /\          
  |      |                       ||               _____
  +------+                       ||              /     \___
+-----------+          +----------+           __|          \
| Компьютер | <======> |   Роутер | <======> /    Интернет  \
+-----------+ |      | +----------+ |        |______________|
              |      |              |
    Локальный IP     |              |
    192.168.1.2      |              |
                     |              |
           Локальный IP            Внешний IP
           192.168.1.1             128.12.32.232
```

Сейчас обычно [роутер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D1%80%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80) (он же маршрутизатор) представляет «коробочку, которая раздаёт wi-fi», но это может быть и оборудование на стороне провайдера. Так вот, из внешней стороны интренета виден только «*Внешний IP*», о внутреннем устройстве сети за ним удалённая машина может догадываться только по очень косвенным признакам. Именно этот адрес и показывается в поисковике по запросу «мой айпи»

*Привязка* (*bind*) сокета осуществляется только к **адресу локального интерфейса**. Здесь надо понимать, что **не** «адрес присваивается сокету», а именно сокет привязывается к уже известному ОС адресу, который назначен одному из сетевых адаптеров. Фактически это нужно, чтобы ограничить, с каких интерфейсов приложение будет обрабатывать соединения/пакеты, чтобы, например, если сервер обслуживает только клиентов на *localhost*'е, злоумышленник из локальной сети не смог бы к нему подключиться, или на том же порту локальную сеть обслуживал бы другой клиент.

Посмотреть адреса локального интерфейсов можно в выводе `ifconfig` (или `ipconfig` в win). Также можно привязать сокет к специальному адресу `0.0.0.0`, чтобы обрабатывать пакеты пришедшие на все локальные интерфейсы данной машины:

```
net.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (inet_addr ("0.0.0.0"));
```

но лучше воспользоваться специальной константой:

```
net.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);
```

Кроме того стоит помнить, что `bind ()` управляет **только** локальной машиной; он ни как не влияет на поведение роутера, поэтому когда сервер привяжется к локальному порту, удалённый «пк друга» не увидит его открытым и не сможет на него подключиться т.к. он увидит только роутер. Но если «друг» придёт в гости и подключится к локальной сети, то он сможет обратиться к твоему серверу напрямую по твоему внутреннему адресу.

---

Собственно для того, чтобы дать возможность подключаться внешним клиентам можно сделать одно из двух:

- Переконфигурировать сеть так, чтобы внешний «белый» IP, выдавался напрямую одному из сетевых интерфейсов компьютера. Не всегда возможно, является редким явлением сегодня, требует переконфигурации сети и сопряжено с рядом других неудобств.
- Пробросить порты на роутере, (если роутер находится под твоим контролем, а не где-то у провайдера и ему выдан внешний адрес). Конкретное описание, как это сделать см. в руководстве к своему оборудованию.

Также, чтобы подключиться мог именно «друг», есть другие варианты, в частности VPN или тунелирование, но это уже другая история.

Comment: Благодарю за столь информативный ответ, все очень понятно:-)  Я себе это представлял совершенно иначе)

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос, который Вы задаёте, на самом деле, весьма непрост. И для ответа на него пришлось бы много чего писать. Поэтому Вам и отвечают в комментах довольно критически.

Но вот на вопрос

> книгу "как научиться создавать клиент- сервер" или что то подобное не
>   видел.

я могу дать ответ. Таких книг даже несколько:

1. У. Р. Стивенс, Б. Феннер, Э. М. Рудофф "UNIX. Разработка сетевых приложений" 3-е издание
2. Ш. Уолтон "Создание сетевых приложений в среде Linux""
3. Камер, Дуглас Э., Стивене, Дэвид Л. "Сети TCP/IP, том 3. Разработка приложений типа клиент/сервер для Linux/POSIX".

Comment: Оо, спасибо за книжки , а не можете подсказать куда дальше идти? Я вроде бы сейчас освоил язык си, и мне предлагают обучаться алгоритмам, может сначала с сетей начать?